# Prove that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Supose $g:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function of class $C^2$, and $\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y^2}$. If we define $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y)=g(x+y,x-y)$, prove that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}=0$. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g(x+y,x-y)=g(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$ (where $\tilde{x}=x+y$ and $\tilde{y}=x-y$).  Use the chain rule to show that

\begin{align*}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\,\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial \tilde{x}^2}-\dfrac{\partial ^2g}{\partial \tilde{y}^2}=0.\end{align*}